# What test to use to determine if someone is actually answering on a questionnaire vs. responding randomly

Tags: hypothesis-testing, survey

I am new at using statistical tests and here is a very easy question but I cannot find the answer online.

I am going to send out a survey and my professor told me that I should ask the same question three times but then rewrite it somewhat differently in order to test whether people filled in the survey with attention instead of just clicking the dots as fast as possible. There is a test which you can use in order to see if the three answers regarding the same variable are somewhat the same.

What is the name of this test?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question will have a better chance of getting a good answer if the title is more descriptive. Also, I deleted your signature line as the site adds one automatically.

Comment: Thank you Peter. Will use a descriptive title in case I have another question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about running a reliability analysis? You can input the data into a program such as SPSS and run a reliability analysis to see if the participants answered the question consistently (and, in turn, if the questions are related to the same idea/construct). See article below, particularly the section on "Internal Consistency Reliability":

http://psychology.about.com/od/researchmethods/f/reliabilitydef.htm

Comment: Thanks for this response! I googled "reliability analysis" and I found the test I needed: Cronbachs alfa test. Thank you very much!

Comment: internal consistency is a test scale characteristic, not a peson characteristic. It sounds like what Laurens is asking for is a person related characteristic.

Comment: Here's an example of 3 of my survey questions on consistency: 1. My clients offer conflicting information. 2. The information received from my clients is consistent. 3. There are times when the information provided by clients seems contradictory. These questions can be answered by a 7-point likert scale. Don't really know whether this is a person or a test scale characteristic. But I think the right test to see whether the answers are consistent is to use the Cronbachs Alfa Test. Thanks for the response RJ.